# How to find on the Windows 7 who and when use(d) a certain share?

Tags: networking, security, windows-7, network-share

We have a workstation using Win7 on a LAN with a domain. On that workstation we set up some network shares.

Can we find who used (user name and/or computer name) and when the shares?

Note that we know about *Computer Management > System Tools > Shared Folders > Open Files*. We don't want to see so much real-time who's using the shares but we are interested more in a logging solution, ideally interpreting / using the data from Win7's Event Viewer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To monitor access to shared objects you need to [enable auditing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738931%28WS.10%29.aspx) on the computer providing the shared objects.